# I can't enable passive mod in my ftp server

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have installed vsftpd in a Ubuntu server 20.04. The service works fine, i have connection with it and tha active mode work fine. I tried to enable passive mode but doesn't works. This is my configuration.
https://pastebin.pl/view/ffe6c237

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**
The problem was with the ufw service. I disabled the service and it worked. It's not necessary to stop the servce, you just need to specify the port allowed.